# Why does `this` have different addresses in subclasses?

Tags: c++

Why does the `d` instance have different `this` addresses? Someone told me that in OOP languages, a derived class is simply all the members of the base class, followed by members of its own.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct A
{
    int member;
};

struct B : public virtual A
{
    void print_b() { std::cout << static_cast<void*>(this) << " " << static_cast<void*>(&this->member) << std::endl; }
};

struct C : public virtual A
{
    void print_c() { std::cout << static_cast<void*>(this) << " " << static_cast<void*>(std::addressof(member)) << std::endl; }
};

struct D : public B, public C 
{
    void print() 
    { 
        print_b();
        print_c();
    }
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    d.print();
}
```

[Online outputs](http://cpp.sh/5r6oo):

> 0x700af9347b90 0x700af9347ba0
>
> 0x700af9347b98 0x700af9347ba0

Comment: Why would they be the same? It's the address of `B` instance and `C` instance inside `d`. `d` itself has yet another `this` address.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Someone told me that in OOP languages, a derived class is simply all the members of the base class, followed by members of its own. So only one instance is created, insteade of 4.

Comment: @Phuc It is. But you have two bases! Not every `C` is part of an object that has a `B`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `B` and `C` base sub objects are distinct objects in relation to each other and cannot share an address.

*Empty* base sub objects could be exempted from the requirement of having a unique address, but `B` and `C` are not empty.

Comment: and because `B` and `C` are not empty class.

Comment: Made a small change of phrasing, which I think is what you meant to begin with. Please roll back if I was wrong.

Comment: @StoryTeller your change seems good. After all, there are exceptions where empty base optimization isn't allowed.